# Is it possible to run a node.js script as a module with the node command (without using package.json)?

Tags: node.js

Let's say I have a `code.js` file with the following node.js script:

```js
const axios = require('axios')

async function getData(){
    const response = await axios.get('https://mypage.com.br')
    console.log(response.data)
}
getData()
```

If I execute it with `node code.js` it works perfectly fine... However, I'd like to execute it as a module, just so I can use the `import` statement and use the `await` command as top level. I'd like to accomplish that without creating a project with a `package.json` file. My final result would be something like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios' 

const response = await axios.get('https://mypage.com.br')
console.log(response.data)
```

I haven't managed to make it work with the `node` command. I know there's a `--input-type=module` parameter I can use with it. But I've tried running `node --input-type=module code.js` and I've received the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

So, that means it's not even being recognized as a module yet. Is it possible to do? Can I execute an isolated script with the command `node` as a module (while using `await` on top level)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rename the file to `name.mjs`. This `--input-type` parameter only applies to STDIN and `--eval`-d files.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after renaming the file. But I'm in a very specific case where renaming the file is not a viable solution. Isn't there any way of declaring it as a module without renaming the file?

Comment: No. There isn't.

Answer (score 11):

This isn't really possible from the command line. You have only two options for making your file ESM.

1. Edit `package.json` to have the following key and value.

   ```json
   {
     "type": "module"
   }
   ```
2. Change the file extensions from `.js` to `.mjs`. The *m* stands for *module*.

In conclusion, the flag below doesn't help with changing the type to module.

```
$ node code.js --input-type=module
```

Comment: From my answer: The --input-type flag only applies to --eval'd or source STDIN files.

Answer (score 3):

A different alternative without renaming the file is executing the code with a `pipe` in `bash`. The following command works fine as a module:

```
cat code.js | node --input-type=module
```

Comment: too bad there is an option like `node --type=module ./code.js`. would be cool.