# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when running child_process

Tags: node.js, typescript, memory-leaks, puppeteer, child-process

I am utilizing Puppeteer for web scraping. However, I've encountered an issue where there's a gradual increase in memory consumption. This phenomenon is quite common when using the Puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth. To address this concern, I intend to execute the scraping process within a child_process. By doing so, the scraping activities will take place within a distinct process that is independent of the primary Node.js process.

I followed this tutorial: [How to simply workaround RAM-leaking libraries like Puppeteer. Universal way to fix RAM leaks once and forever](https://devforth.io/blog/how-to-simply-workaround-ram-leaking-libraries-like-puppeteer-universal-way-to-fix-ram-leaks-once-and-forever/)

The challenge I'm currently facing is that while testing this setup in a simplified function

```
function somthing() {
    console.log('Yessss');
    return;
}

somthing();
```

I am able to obtain the desired results. `Child process stdout: Yessss`

function that create the child process:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

export async function createChildProcess<T>() {
    console.log('DD');

    try {
        const childProcess = spawn('node', ['src/scraping-utils/poppings-child.ts']); // Use .js extension

        childProcess.stdout.on('data', (data: any) => {
            console.log(`Child process stdout: ${data}`);
        });

        childProcess.stderr.on('data', (data: any) => {
            console.error(`Child process stderr: ${data}`);
        });

        childProcess.on('close', (code: any) => {
            console.log(`Child process exited with code ${code}`);
        });

        childProcess.on('error', (error: any) => {
            console.error(`Child process error: ${error}`);
        });

        // You can optionally await the child process to exit
        await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
            childProcess.on('exit', () => {
                resolve();
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`An error occurred: ${error}`);
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt to run the actual usable function, I encounter this errer:

[image]

its did not recognised the import: `import { Browser, BrowserContext, Page } from 'puppeteer';`

using require dos not work also naming the file from `.ts`  to `.mts`  wont work.

using require dos not work also naming the file from `.ts`  to `.mts`  wont work.

what i exspect from it is to recignise the import exsactly as it was doing before using `child_process`

Comment: Puppeteer shouldn't leak memory by default. I would fix the fundamental problem rather than hacking around it with child processes. Node can't execute TypeScript without compiling it first, last I checked, so you might want to run a `.mjs` file or use Deno. Or add [`"type": "module"` to the package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71814733/6243352).